# Instance is still accessible via public DNS but has a "stopped" state in my dashboard

Tags: amazon-ec2

I created a few micro Amazon Linux instances a week ago for learning and test purposes.  Logged-in via WinSCP and PUtty.  Terminated all but one and "stopped" the one test instance I created.

I started to play with EC2 instances again today and inserted the public DNS from my notes (ec2-50-17-13-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com) into a browser and got this:

> "Congratulations! Your AWS Elastic Beanstalk PHP application is now running on your own dedicated environment in the AWS Cloud"

However, when I go to my AWS dashboard, my test instance is in a "stopped" state and I have no Beanstalk applications running in my dashboard.

When I "started" my one remaining test EC2 instance, the public DNS displayed there is different.

Any suggestions for how I can backtrack to figure out why this instance is still running?  My usage reports are okay, but I'm confused about this instance that should not be running.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that you don't have a beanstalk running? Also, you can find out what's happening with the routing using Route 53.

Comment: When instance was stopped, AWS has reused its IP address to give it to another customer. When you started that instance again, you were given another IP.

Comment: In my AWS dashboard under Elastic Beanstalk, it tells me "You do not have any AWS Elastic Beanstalk applications launched."

Comment: I did not assign an elastic IP to these test instances so if the external DNS (ec2-50-17-13-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com) does not stick with the instance until termination of it, then mvp's answer is correct.

Comment: Yes, @mvp is correct. Amazon re-assigns your public IP address/hostname to their pool when you stop an instance. Someone running an Elastic Beanstalk got it :)

Answer (score 2):

When an Amazon Web Services (AWS) Elastic Compute (EC2) instance is stopped, Amazon will typically re-assign the public DNS name assigned to that instance.  In this particular case, the default landing page was unchanged by the new instance/DNS user which caused the identical DNS name (ec2-50-17-13-137.compute-1.amazonaws.com) to appear to be from the original instance referenced in this question.

So when a user "stops" then "starts" an instance in the AWS EC2 control panel, unless an elastic IP has been assigned to that instance, then the user must use the newly assigned Amazon public DNS to access the restarted instance.

Comment: Thanks to @mvp for helping me on this one.